# Which will collide first to the imaginary line? (see the well drawn diagram)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, inertial-frames

[image: **see the image **]

So, we are having two similar blocks of mass $m$ each. Neglect the size of blocks and fixed pulley. For each block length between blocks and point of contact with pulley is $l$ initially. The block in air is released, tell which block will collide with the imaginary wall first?
If we assume that block is released at say, $t_{0} = 0 ~ sec$,

MY ATTEMPT:
This is how I am thinking please tell what's wrong or/and what I am missing?

1. The block in air will try to move vertically downwards due to gravity $g$ acting on it.
2. But will not move in vertical straight line due to string's tension.
3. As tension is produced block on surface will move towards right.
4. Observing situation at any time $t$ ( before it collides).

Let block on surface moved distance $x$ towards right, the distance between this block and imaginary line is $l - x$ then.

The block in air is having a string length of $l + x$ right now, it is not descending in circular motion.

Can relative motion be used here? If yes how ?

I am not able to proceed further, please light the path, I have tried to explain my best.

Comment: Hi Kuldeep Saharan. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: thanks sir, I will mention it now after .